# IIS Server available on IP address on the machine where it's installed, but not through other machines

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis

I am working with WCF Web service, I have IIS installed on machine and it's working fine, on my machine, but I want other systems on network to access it or ultimately access my web service through this over ip,
for this purpose when I type

**http://192.168.179.1:80/**
in my browser on the mahcine where IIS is installed, it responds perfectly(opens IIS Windows), 
similarly when I type
**http://192.168.179.1:80/service/GetEmployees.svc** (my web service)
it works fine.

but when I type these addresses on some other machine's browser on the same network, it doesnt respond.

I need to mention here that I have disabled Firewall, and I have enabled 
**World Wide Web services** through inbound rules already but nothing is working.

where am I going wrong or what should I do? 
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.
regards.

Comment: Is this IIS Express or IIS?

Comment: are using IIS Express or IIS? your firewall security is open for your network?

Comment: Hi @Waleed, can you try to access it using a full name of your server including your domain name(if any), instead of using an IP address?

Comment: @ZaidMirza Using IIS, and yes Firewall security is open.

Comment: @sagar can you please give me a pattern example to do it?

Comment: @WaleedZulficar Go to 'My Computer/This PC' of your IIS Server machine => right click and select 'Properties' => There you will find a 'Full Computer Name' => use this name instead of IP address

Comment: @WaleedZulficar have you deployed your services on IIS while accessing it on your own  system? or your IDE do deployment when you run your application from IDE?

Comment: @ZaidMirza I've deployed it on IIS properly, and I run it through IIS.

Comment: @sagar I am able to access it with computer's name on my machine still it's not working when i try accessing it from my phone's browser which is on the same network.

Comment: @Waleed what do you mean by same network? How do you configured network settings on your mobile?